# Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request C# and Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax call, and in my local environment it works, but when I go up to my server it starts giving problem.

The error that appears:
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request
By F-12 Google Chrome appears:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

JQuery:

```
function converter(origem, destino, tipo) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "@Url.Action("Converter", "Home")",
      data: {aCoordenada: origem.val(), aTipo: tipo},
      success: function (msg) {
          destino.val(msg);
      }
  });
};
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult Converter(string aCoordenada, string aTipo)
{
    var orientacao = "";
    aCoordenada = aCoordenada.Replace(".", ",");
    decimal coordenada = Convert.ToDecimal(aCoordenada);
    coordenada = Math.Abs(coordenada);

    int coorHora = (int)coordenada;
    coordenada = (coordenada - coorHora) * 60;
    int coorMin = (int)coordenada;
    coordenada = (coordenada - coorMin) * 60;
    decimal coorSeg = Math.Round(coordenada, 3);

    return Json(coorHora.ToString() + "° " + coorMin.ToString() + "' " + coorSeg.ToString() + "'' " + orientacao, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

URL send parameters:

```
http://localhost/Home/Converter?aCoordenada=-49.06022071838379&aTipo=LNG
```

[]s!

Comment: A 500 error indicates that there is something wrong with your server side code. Have you watched the request / response in you console? That may give you some clues. This is not a jQuery problem.

Comment: wouldn't changing the `.` to a `,` give you an invalid string to convert to a decimal?

Answer (score 0):

My local environment is standard en-Br and the server is international ...
I added in my web.config the command and it worked ...

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR"/>
```

tks for the help